# How do I customize unity on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: unity, themes

I have been searching some themes for unity on ubuntu 13.04, the simplest way to install themes that I use is copying the theme into /usr/share/themes, this worked but just for a few themes, but not to this the UNION BLUE theme. I really be grateful if someone can explain me how to transform my unity into this.

[image]

It would be really nice  if a brave man explain this  in the most detailed way and it would be even better if you explain how to change the panel like in the image. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I find Unity Tweak Tool very powerful read here: http://lifehacker.com/5982844/unity-tweak-tool-customizes-every-inch-of-your-ubuntu-desktop

Open up a terminal and do as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Also check out this theme call elementaryish which I think is exactly what you are looking for: http://www.noobslab.com/2013/04/elementaryish-theme-for-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a .themes directory in your home folder so you can extract and test theme sets without installing them to your root system, also make sure that the directory containing the gtk-2.0 or gtk-3.0 directory is the one copied into your theme folder...

Installing Tweak Ubuntu can make this easier also as it contains an option to install themes for you...